# Having two seperate routes in node/express, where one accepts all the requests

Tags: node.js, rest, express, websocket, routes

In my node/express app, I have the following `app.js` file with the following routing

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('./middleware/logger');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})); 


app.use('/wsserver', require('./routes/wsroutes'));    
app.use('/', require('./routes/company')); 


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('server runs on port ', port);
});
```

Every request that goes to `http://localhost:8080/wsserver`, is handeld by wsroutes. I am planning to setup a websockets server in there, but for now contains

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); 


router.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.send('ws');
})


module.exports = router;
```

The `/` handles all the other requests and its handled by the `company` that contains

```
router.get('/',(req, res)=>{ ....
router.get('/:companyName/:id?/:employ?',(req, res)=>{   ...
etc
```

As you can guess, the problem is that when I go to `http://localhost:8080/wsserver`, is handled by the `/` route and the `company` route. I get the interface and the message `no company named wsserver` , because the `wsserver` becomes an argument in the `router.get('/:companyName/:id?/:employ?'` route.

How can I still have both routes, not change the `/` one and have them both work correctly? I tried to change positions in the routes like so

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/company')); 
app.use('/wsserver', require('./routes/wsroutes'));
```

ans still nothing.

What else can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: If you remove `app.use('/', require('./routes/company'));` does it work? (The first matching route will handle the request, so your original code should work.) Maybe you need to add a trailing `/` to your request.

Comment: Surprisingly no!. I get `GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)` and `GET http://localhost:3000/wsserver/undefined/undefined 404 (Not Found)` in the console.  I updated my answer, it now contains all the code of the `wsserver` routing handling file . Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: `router.get('/',` does not match all routes only `/` so i would assume `http://localhost:3000/wsserver/` works. If you want to match all routes you could use ``router.get('*',``

Comment: I commented out the `app.use('/',` route. I only have the `app.use('/wsserver', require('./routes/wsroutes')); ` working. I still get the `404` errors when I go to `http://localhost:8080/wsserver`. I try to send `res.sendFile('./wsserver/windex.html');` in my wsserver route and I get the UI of the `/` route.So nothing works. I dont know how to debug this.I am lost.

Comment: Ahhh wait, wait , wait. I am an idiot. I was trying to hit the endpoints via my Vue app, so I was using a url like `http://localhost:8080/`. But the working port of node is 3000. If I go to `http://localhost:3000/` everything works fine. I am so stupid. Sorry for this. Thank you for your time.